# VS Code autocomplete Python dunder-methods

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Once typed in VS Code *add* autocomplete provides the option __ add __. The same works for many other dunder-methods. But with __ sub __ it does not autocomplete.

How to fix it? Is there any plug-in for that?

```
class ListMath:
def __init__ (self, ls=None):
    self.lst_math = [] if not ls else [x for x in ls if type(x) in (int, float)]

def __add__ (self, other):
    if type(other) in (int, float):
        return ListMath([x + other for x in self.lst_math])

def __radd__ (self, other):
    return self + other

def __iadd__ (self, other):
    if type(other) in (int, float):
        self.lst_math = [x + other for x in self.lst_math]
        return self

def __sub__ (self, other):
    if type(other) in (int, float):
        return ListMath([x - other for x in self.lst_math])
```

Comment: Can you provide an example class where this occurs? I remember any classes that implements both `__add__` and `__sub__` off the top of my head, and custom classes implementing them do not reproduce this issue.

Comment: Have you defined `__sub__`?

Comment: @Shorn fow example,
`class ListMath:
   def __ add __ (self, other):
        if type(other) in (int, float):
            return ListMath([x + other for x in self.lst_math])

    def __ radd __ (self, other):
        return self + other

    def __ iadd __ (self, other):
        if type(other) in (int, float):
            self.lst_math = [x + other for x in self.lst_math]
            return self

    def __ sub __ (self, other):
        if type(other) in (int, float):
            return ListMath([x - other for x in self.lst_math])`

Comment: @PolinaBobrova taking that code fragment and properly formatting it (you should include it in your question properly formatted since Python is a whitespace sensitive language and thus the exact formatting is important), `__sub__` is appropriately auto-completed.

Comment: Why is there a space between the underline and **add** in the method you defined? For example, it should be `__add__` instead of `__ add __`.

Comment: @Shorn well, for me even properly formatted code is not getting autocompleted...

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT **add** and **sub** are standard Python methods, I do not get your question